# SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: after upgrading to Rails 4.1.8

Tags: sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

My app has worked for over a year with the current code, but after upgrading to Rails 4.1.8 I get the following error:
[image]

This is a music review site where users have many pins, which are the reviews, and the pins belong_to users. The pins have a 'year' which is a string. The users rank the albums that they review so that the site will create their top ten list for the year. This page shows all of the users who posted a top ten list.

The pages controller:

```
def tens2013
    @users = User.includes(:pins).where('pins.year=?', '2013')
    @pins = Pin.all
    @pins_ten = Pin.where(:year => '2013', :rank => ['10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2', '1'], :rank => !nil)
end
```

The view:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
        <ul  class="ver2 well"> 
            <li><div class="reviewer"><%= link_to (image_tag user.image(:small)), user %><h4><%= user.name %></h4></div></li> 
            <% user.pins.order('rank DESC').each do |pin| %>
                <% if pin.year == '2013' && (pin.rank == 10 || pin.rank == 9 || pin.rank == 8 || pin.rank == 7 || pin.rank == 6 || pin.rank == 5 || pin.rank == 4 || pin.rank == 3 || pin.rank == 2 || pin.rank == 1 )  %> 
                  <li><div class="span2"><%= link_to (image_tag pin.image(:medium)), pin %><br/> #<%= pin.rank %> <br/> <%= truncate(pin.album, length:15) %></div></li>
                <% end %>
            <% end %> 
        </ul>   
    <% end %>
```

I'm assuming that something changed in rails that doesn't play nice with the .where method. I've been googling it, but I can't seem to find the change.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and hopefully this will help others who upgraded Rails. There's a great blog post here: http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

Along the process of upgrading Rails I needed to add config.eager_load = false to my development.rb file

You can read the great explanation of .includes vs .eager_load in that blog post, but by changing .eager_load to false the activerecord query wasn't able to join the two tables.

I changed

```
@users = User.includes(:pins).where('pins.year=?', '2013')
```

to

```
@users = User.eager_load(:pins).where('pins.year=?', '2013')
```

and it all worked correctly again.